# mongodb in node.js connections today

Tags: node.js, mongodb

When using the native mongo.db driver for node, should I open 1 connection per application, per page "serve", or open and close it whenever I need?

I've seen a few [older answers](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/issues/84) but I know the project is always developing so I want to know what it the status today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a situation that will change; opening a new connection to a server will be less performant than using an established connection.

*Note:* this is the general case for server applications, and not specific to MongoDB.

Typical overhead includes:

- resolving server names to IPs
- establishing network connection to server
- per connection memory allocated on the server

For MongoDB in particular:

- opening a new connection means a new socket connection and thread on the server
- each connection (as of MongoDB 2.0) allocates 1Mb of RAM on the server (see also: [Checking Memory Usage](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Checking+Server+Memory+Usage))
- there is a per process limit on open files/connections (see also: [Too Many Open Files](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Too+Many+Open+Files))

For the MongoDB Node.js driver you can take advantage of connection pooling by setting the [poolSize](http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/server.html) in the constructor.  A blog post with an example of using this: [Node.js: Connection Pools and MongoDB](http://technosophos.com/2011/10/26/nodejs-connection-pools-and-mongodb.html).

Comment: this is not the case for every server. Some servers only process one concurrent query per connection (e.g. postgres), so you may need to open another one. Sometimes if you have a long unused connection you hold a resource for other optional clients.

Comment: @YaronNaveh: the general performance issue of connection setup and associated resource usage is still true in [Postgres](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication,_Clustering,_and_Connection_Pooling#Connection_Pooling_and_Acceleration).  A separate issue is how your application or driver manages reusing/closing connections as well as concurrency.  The typical DB driver concept to minimize resource usage is using a [connection pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool) which maintains a set of active connections available for reuse.

Comment: the pool allows you to open connection each time you want (and if you're lucky you'll get on opened one from the pool). what surprised me in mongo is that you keep one global connection for the whole app. what is special in mongo that allows to do this? Is it b/c mongo has no transactions (which require different connections)? Is it b/c mongo is more efficient doing concurrent requests on the same connection?